# How to start creating voice chat application using Adobe Flex and Red5?

Tags: apache-flex, chat, red5, voice

I will create a voice chat application with Adobe Flex and I want use the opensource Red5 as a server.
But, I confuse how to start it. it's possible just use NetStream and NetConnection?
Or are there any others tutorial can help me?
Please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seriously have you even bothered to look for examples?
[Google is your friend.](http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&=&q=flex%20chat%20example&aq=f&aqi=g1g-v1g-b1&aql=&oq=#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&pq=flex%20chat%20example&xhr=t&q=flex%20red5%20chat%20example&cp=10&pf=p&sclient=psy&source=hp&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=flex%20red5%20chat%20example&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=822bf32b5c0e0691&biw=1287&bih=672)

Comment: I like how the first link is a complete working tutorial that answers the question... I would give +2 to you sir, if I could. :)

Comment: Exactly why I posted that link. TY